# Finding if a element just holding one element and hide parent element if true

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript not jquery solution for this one. Any help would be great. I need check if the p tag just has a br tag and if so then hide the p tag.

```
<blockquotes> 

<p>

<br> </br> < so if this is the only element then hide the p tag 

</p>

</blockquotes>
```

Comment: There's no closing `</br>` in HTML and also you have empty text nodes before and after the `<br>`. So, if you have `<p>some text <br></p>` that wouldn't be removed, but if there's white space beside the `<br>` tag you would remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
function hidePTags() {
    var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < pTags.length; i++) {
        if (pTags[i].children.length == 1 && pTags[i].children[0].tagName == "br") {
            pTags[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: var pTags = document.getElementByTagName('p'); it says this isn't a function

Comment: @Kelly notice the 'S' that I added to that line. "element" -> "elements"

Comment: Thanks so far I get this now  pTags[i].children[0].tagName.equals is not a function

Comment: @Kelly my bad...Just realised .equals needed to just use an "==" sign.

Comment: @Kelly if this answer helped you, you can upvote it and/or mark is as an answer to the left.

Comment: http://michaelscimeca.com/problem.jpg the script seem to be right, but doesn't effect it. I have add a link to show you whats up.

Comment: @Kelly Are you sure that you are calling the function?

Comment: I pasted what i got going on <script>

function hidePTags() {
    var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < pTags.length; i++) {
        if (pTags[i].children.length == 1 && pTags[i].children[0].tagName == "br") {
            pTags[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}


window.onload = function() {
 hidePTags();
};



</script>

Comment: Okay, im just testing this now in JSFiddle

Comment: <blockquote><p>
<!--MA-WS-C22--><br>
</p>